# why doesnt this timer work

Tags: vb.net, timer

nothing happens when this is started ive never used a timer before so its probably something simple i cant find online i know the sql wont work but i can do that later

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\maddog.accdb;")
    Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
    Dim current_time As String = DateTime.Now
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim Sql As String = "select from bookings where (app_date=todaysdate) and (start_time= )"
        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, connection)
        Dim DataReader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        If DataReader.HasRows Then MsgBox("ready")
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the Tick event of a Windows Forms Timer. How do you have defined this timer? Did you set the Interval property? Did you call Start or set Enabled = True?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timer tick handler not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057542/timer-tick-handler-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

Common mistakes with timers are:

1. You need to start it with either timer.enabled or timer.start.
2. You might need to reset the timer in the tick handler, depending on the type of timer and property settings. (There is the timer control, system.timers.timer, and system.threading.timer, each of which is a little different.)
3. You might need to disable temporarily it in the tick handler to make sure it doesn't re-enter the handler and cause problems.